# Question about properites of tensor product

Tags: matrices, tensors

For $A$, $B$ and $I$ being 2 by 2 matrices and $I$ being the identity,

1. Is $((A\otimes I\otimes I) + (I\otimes A\otimes I) + (I\otimes I\otimes A))\otimes B$

   = $(A\otimes I\otimes I)\otimes B + (I\otimes A\otimes I)\otimes B + (I\otimes I\otimes A)\otimes B$?
2. Is $(A\otimes I\otimes I)\otimes B + (I\otimes A\otimes I)\otimes B + (I\otimes I\otimes A)\otimes B$=

$(A\otimes B)\otimes (I\otimes I)\otimes (I\otimes I) + (I\otimes I)\otimes (A\otimes B)\otimes (I\otimes I) + (I\otimes I)\otimes(I\otimes I)\otimes(A\otimes B)$?

I ask 2 because I stumbled upon the RHS of 2 and hope to know if it can be factored out as the LHS of 1. So basically I reverse the line of reason to ask these two questions. And now, looking at the LHS of 1., I also want to know:

3. Is $((A\otimes I\otimes I) + (I\otimes A\otimes I) + (I\otimes I\otimes A))\otimes B$
   = $((A\otimes I\otimes I) + (I\otimes A\otimes I) + (I\otimes I\otimes A))\otimes (B\otimes I\otimes I)$
   = $((A\otimes I\otimes I) + (I\otimes A\otimes I) + (I\otimes I\otimes A))\otimes (I\otimes B\otimes I)$
   =$((A\otimes I\otimes I) + (I\otimes A\otimes I) + (I\otimes I\otimes A))\otimes (I\otimes I\otimes B)$?

Comment: My eyes...Ive never seen more tensor product symbols together in one place :)